# Notification sidebar style makes links jump on hover

Tags: bug, design, sidebar

Moving the course across the links in the sidebar makes them jump:

[image]

This is with FF 54.0.

Comment: With FF 55.0 it looks fine for me.

Comment: FF 56.0, same problem.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04. I just ran a full `aptitude safe-upgrade`.

Comment: Can *not* reproduce on [SO] and [cs.SE], so the specific style of [tex.SE] (and its meta) may be the issue.

Comment: Maybe something ubuntu specific? I tried with Mac and Fedora

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue with FF 56.0 on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: FF 56.0 win10 doesn't have any issue. Looks like your font rendering is problematic

Comment: @Marijn Interesting! Any ideas where to look? It's not as if I force a certain font to be used, or had user styles running. (Not for such formatting, that is.)

Comment: FF 52 (ok, a little bit aged ;-)) on Linux does not show this feature.